# How to apply an R function to each row & combine results

Tags: r, nlp

I have a dataframe with text data, where one column contains the text of interest & other columns are metadata related to this text.

```
text     metadata_1  metadata_2  
x        abc         123         
y        def         456
z        ghi         789
```

For a single row, I have a function that:

- Runs the text through the Google Natural Language API via the googlelanguager package, which returns a set of lists with various NLP results (entities, sentences, tokens, etc.)
- Stores the returned “entities” list object in a dataframe
- Combines the entity results with the analyzed-text’s metadata (so there is one row per entity, and the metadata fields repeat)

```
get_entities <- function(x) {
  
  # run text through google nlp api with gl_nlp()
  nlp_result <- x["text"] %>% 
    gl_nlp()
  
  # store entities results in dataframe
  entities <- as.data.frame(nlp_result[["entities"]]) 
  
  # bind text info with entities into for the analyzed text
  bind_cols(x, entities)  
}
```

The output looks something like:

```
text     metadata_1  metadata_2  entity        entity_type
x        abc         123         Joe           PERSON
x        abc         123         Chicago       LOCATION
x        abc         123         World Series  EVENT
```

But I want to perform the same operation over each row in my text data set: analyzing the text field, isolating the entity results from the get_nlp() list output, and joining those results back to the corresponding text metadata. Then, ideally, join the individual results into one location.

```
text     metadata_1  metadata_2   entity         entity_type
x        abc         123          Joe            PERSON
x        abc         123          Chicago        LOCATION
x        abc         123          World Series   EVENT
y        def         456          2002           DATE
y        def         456          New York       LOCATION
z        ghi         789          2016           DATE
```

I have been having trouble identifying the best approach to iterate on my dataset & combine the results. Is there a method that makes the most sense for combining data sets from a function as part of a `for` loop or `apply`?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowwise`, apply the `get_entities` on the `cur_data()`, store the output in a `list` and `unnest` the `list` output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   rowwise %>%
   summarise(out = list(get_entities(cur_data())), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   unnest(c(out))
```

---

If we want to do this in `*apply`, loop over the sequence of rows, extract the data and apply the `get_entities`

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i)
       get_entities(df1[i,, drop = FALSE]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may `apply` the function `get_entities` for each row and combine the result.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, get_entities))
```